# Parse String and Append Parameters to All URLs in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have a string which includes URLs within HTML. I'd like to add parameters to each URL.

```
$my_string = "See our full range of <a href="http://www.mysite.com/cat.php?cPath=8" target="_blank">some category</a> online and also our popular <a href="http://www.mysite.com/product.php?products_id=22" target="_blank">some product</a>.";
```

Which should end up as:

```
$my_new_string = "See our full range of <a href="http://www.mysite.com/cat.php?cPath=8&new_param=test" target="_blank">some category</a> online and also our popular <a href="http://www.mysite.com/product.php?products_id=22&new_param=test" target="_blank">some product</a>.";
```

Comment: preg_replace, but couldn't work it out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regexp :

```
$my_new_string = preg_replace('`<a (.*)href="(.+)"(.*)>`iU', '<a $1href="$2&new_param=test"$3>', $my_string);
```

Comment: That works great - thanks. To help me learn, could you explain what the backticks do here and also $1, $2 and $3? I understand everything else.

Comment: OK, the manual is clear about $1 etc. These are the found instances in order. Just the backticks I don't get.

Comment: You can use whatever you want to surround a pcre, people usually use / or # but when matching urls you should use something else or you will have to escape the / or # inside your expression ... Long time ago when I was bothered with escaping stuff I decided to always use backticks to surround my pcre as it is not used that often for writing, could have used ~ as well, or even ° ...